# Access objects created by .net application

Tags: c#, winforms

At runtime is it possible to access & modify objects created by a .net application?

When we create a reference or value type the objects/prop values are stored at specific memory location,
I wonder whether we can access that memory location and set a custom value.
This may sound like hacking(spying an exe) but I am just curious whether it is possible

**UPDATE**
Consider following program:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "Test";
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This console application generates an exe,
When I run the exe, it waits for user input,
While it is waiting for input I want to change value of variable `s` from other application

Comment: Search for "reflection".

Comment: I think we cannot access properties of a running exe using reflection

Comment: What are "properties of a running exe"? It is unclear what you are asking. Edit your question to show a step-by-step explanation of which application does what.

Comment: So you want to attach to a running program and inspect its data? That sounds like a job for a debugger, such as Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what do you mean by "access & modify objects".

If you are talking about objects properties values - yes of course. It is possible, even for **private members** by using so called [*Reflection*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty");
propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, "SomeValue", null);
```

If your are talking abount changing object's structure stored in memory location, like changing its methods, adding/removing fields etc - it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `I want to modify property value at runtime i.e. after running an exe`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using `Reflection`, it's very powerful and it still amazes me sometimes with what you can do with it. Probably best for you to do a bit of research to see if this is exactly what you want.

Here is a Microsoft overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which explains it reasonably well. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET) link it what I used to learn a lot about reflection and I always recommend it to others. Try it out and then search for more specific questions, there are many good questions and answers here on stackoverflow.

If this isn't what you want, then you can modify anything through a memory editor, but this is well out of my knowledge area and you really need to know how/why you are wanting to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to attach to a running program and inspect its state. That is normally a job for a debugger, such as Visual Studio.

In its Debug menu, you'll find an option to "Attach to Process" that lists all running processes. After you select the process of the program you're looking to inspect, Visual Studio will show the current state as far as it can determine. Knowing this process, you should probably do a few searches to find more information on the approach.

A simple way to accomplish the same given that you have the code for a sample, is to explicitly trigger the debugger from within your code:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "Test";
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // This will trigger a dialog to attach a debugger
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```